# webbrowser open URLs N times get AVR time

Tags: python, selenium, url, browser

I would like to

1. Open URLs: google.com, yahoo.com, bing.com
2. Get average time, that needed to fully load those pages = (get time1 + get time2 + get time3)/3. Close those pages
3. Do this action N times, where N is number that user fill in script and get AVR time for all actions = (N1+N2+...Nn)/n

I started with below code, but its not working. Could you pls help?

```
url='http://google.com'
start = time()
stream=webbrowser.get('windows-default').open(url)
output=stream.read()
end = time()
stream.close
print(end - start)
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: as I know `webbrowser` uses system to open url or filename with default program and it gets `True/False`, not stream, and it can't `read()`. Even if you use `stream = webbrowser.get()` and later `stream.open()` then you still get object which has no `read()`. It is not module `subprocess` which you could get something (if only program send some text to standard output).

Comment: BTW: do you means standard module `webbrowser` or you used name `webbrowser` for `driver` in `Selenium` ? BTW: you forgot `()` in `close()`